# How to add a map in property file for reading in java script

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a series of checkboxes and on click of those check box next series of check box will be displayed.

[image: check box]

All these details fetched from a database. But now i want to make some checkboxes checked based on the selection. I can't keep those details in the database so i want to make a property file and store those map in that.

For example: If I select FQ, then TE must be pre-checked. Now can i have a property file which hold the value of default value details

```
FQ-TE  
FU-FE  
FW-FE
```

All the logic is done in java script so i want to make that propertyfile available for javascript.

Comment: you need to feed json data to javascript that represents properties file data

Comment: thank you for the reply.. can u give me some example link

Comment: 1. create a servlet that reads properties file and renders representative JSON, 2. get that json data in javascript (either by calling via ajax request or by placing it in page itself somewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understood is that you have properties File that mean map in Server Side and you want to access it in Client side JavaScript.

First convert that map into JSON (in server side /JSP).
required jars

1. jackson-core
2. jackson-mapper

   ```
   Map<String,String> yourProperties = ......

   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   String jsonMap = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourproperties);
   ```

Here jsonMap ,after conversion, will look like {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}.

Now add input hidden on jsp to get map in JS.

```
<input type="hidden" id="jsonMap " name="jsonMap " value="${jsonMap}" />
```

Than read input box value in JavaScript by its ID.

```
var jsonMap = $("#jsonMap ");
function get(k){
  return jsonMap [k];
}
```

For example : `alert("value:"+get(1));` 
you can use it in your way

Thank you.